# Session is NULL when running ASP.NET MVC inside of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

If I create an ASP.NET Web Application project and then add an ASP.NET MVC 2 to it using the default routes defined like so

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The Session object is NULL when I try and access it in the action methods of the controllers.  If I change my routes to this.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Everything works just fine.  For whatever reason having the .aspx extension allows for session to be used, but the later doesn't.  I'm using .NET 3.5 for everything.

Any ideas???  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" to the configuration>system.webServer>modules tag in the web.config.